# How to create a Facebook-style Thumbnail Selector using .Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, image-manipulation, thumbnails

I'm looking at implementing a Facebook-style thumbnail creator using ASP.Net MVC but haven't a clue where to start.

The feature in question is most easily-recognised when you upload a new profile picture.  After uploading the image, you are presented with a frame that you can drag around the image to select the area that will appear as your FB profile thumbnail (for your wall, etc).

I'm picking I'd want to use the jQuery UI framework and take advantage of the Draggable feature, but how do I get the coordinates from the chosen position and how do I pass those to .Net to then use as the basis for creating the thumbnail?  Not having much experience at all with image manipulation in .Net (or any other language for that matter), I'm hoping someone will be able to point me to good code samples, tutorials or other general suggestions on how I can achieve what I'm after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this:

- [jQuery Image Crop Plugin](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/)
- [Crop Image in ASP.NET using JCrop, JQuery](http://towardsnext.wordpress.com/2009/04/13/crop-image-in-aspnet-using-jcrop-jquery/)

Comment: Used this plugin before. It's awesome :)

Comment: Looks promising.  Time to dust off my PHP skills.  :-/

Comment: Oh, good show old man!  Very kind to go that little bit extra to find the language I speak.